# ASP.NET Web Forms - Adding Hebrew characters in web.config gives internal server error

Tags: asp.net, webforms, web-config

In my web.config file I am trying to add a key like that:

```
<add key="DefaultUserErrorPayMessage" value="רווית" />
```

but I get an internal server error doing that...
(when I add a value in English letters it works ok)

In the globalization tag I tried to add:

```
<globalization culture="he-IL" uiCulture="he-IL" fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
```

but still no luck there.

I also have this at the top of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Can anyone point out what is the desired solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

OK found the answer...
It is quite stupid I must admit.
when publishing the website the web.config file is ANSI encoded, so need to overwrite this file as UTF-8 encoded.